# Updating values in a new DataRow also affects the DataTable where it's from?

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

this is my first question here,
I have searched around but I couldn't get the answer,
I would be thankful for any help.

Assuming that I have a DataTable named `dtTest` like this

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | AA   |
|  2 | BB   |
+----+------+
```

When I create a new DataRow from `dtTest` and update its value

```cs
DataRow drTest = dtTest.Rows[0];
drTest["name"] = "CC";
```

I thought the only thing I changed is the value in the new object `drTest`,
and it's independence from `dtTest`,
but `dtTest` actually got affected too.

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | CC   |
|  2 | BB   |
+----+------+
```

Why does this action affect the original DataTable?

Comment: because `DataRow` is a reference type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not create a new row but is just the reference to the first row in the table:

```
DataRow drTest = dtTest.Rows[0];  // Rows is a DataRowCollection which contains all table-rows
```

If you want a new row you have these options:

```
DataRow drTest1 = dtTest.NewRow();             // not yet added, you need: dtTest.Rows.Add(drTest1);
DataRow drTest2 = dtTest.Rows.Add();           // already added without values
DataRow drTest3 = dtTest.Rows.Add(1, "test");  // already added with values
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'll make a note of it.

Answer (score 0):

`drTest` is a rowobject of your `dtTest` table. So any changes to `drtest` will affect your datatable `dtTest`

If you want a new row:

```
DataRow drTest1 = dtTest.NewRow();
dtTest["ID"] = 3;
dtTest["name"] = "CC;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, too!